# Does CXF with SOAP 1.1 have a maximum content length for text sent in a request?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

Is there a maximum content length for text sent over CXF with SOAP 1.1? I'm running into an issue where one SOAP request is failing while the other succeeds. The only difference I have pinpointed between these request so far has been the bytes of text I am sending.

I see an error like the following:

```
 checkException (UnexpectedServiceExceptionCheckImpl.java:35) - An unexpected exception was found from source=[DesignService.generate] type=[class javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException] message=[Unmarshalling Error: [was class java.io.IOException] Strange I/O stream, returned 0 bytes on read ]: 
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: [was class java.io.IOException] Strange I/O stream, returned 0 bytes on read 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
    at $Proxy146.generate(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there are any maximums except for memory usage.  Are you seeing any errors?  Can you trace the transaction using wireshark or something?

Comment: I attached the exception that I get. I also took a TCP dump and noticed that this exception gets thrown by the service, before it has finished receiving all the data (data is still being streamed over TCP after this exception is thrown).